# How to get the HTML email from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the Email-content (navchar)(eg:`<p><a></a></p>`) from MS SQL database useing store procedure.
Is there any one know how to get the html code out of the database and transfer it to certain format then send it out as an email ? ps: I need to combine

```
<html><body>+ content+</body></html>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

the best way to do that is have some place holders in your Html in Database and then replace them with values.
for example:
save this in database as a template
[##BODY##]

```
        var template= [read template from database]
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(template);
        var bodyValue ="your body value perhaps user name and blab blab"
        s.Replace("[##BODY##]",bodyValue);
```

and then use that as email body
var emailbody= s.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Select the information you want from the database with a simple `SELECT` statement in your stored proc. It should be returned as a string. From this point on to format your email you have two options ...

A) concatenate the strings like so:

```cs
string stringFromTheDatabase = "<p><a></a></p>";

string concatenatedHTML = "<html><body>" + stringFromTheDatabase + "</body></html>";
```

B) use the `String.Format()` format like so:

```cs
string formattedString = String.Format("<html><body>{0}</body></html>", stringFromTheDatabase);
```

Last but not least: sending it! Personally, I'd just use the built-in `MailMessage` class under the [System.Net.mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) nampespace.